# HostedNetwork/Internet Connection Sharing not assigning IP addresses

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, internet

I currently have internet via a Ethernet cable, and I would like to share that internet connection via a WiFi card. I ran the following commands to setup a WiFi hotspot, and then shared my Ethernet connection to the newly created virtual network adapter.

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=wifi key=12345678
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

But when I attempt to connect from another computer, the network is 'unidentified' and I have 'limited access'. When I ran ipconfig, my IP was '169.254.x.x'. It seems that the hotspot wasn't assigning any IP address and that the DHCP wasn't working.

How would I be able to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: *...and that the DHCP was working.* --- I think you meant that the DHCP server was **not** running/working on the connection sharing computer.

Comment: In your place I used fixips on the localnet until I have a better router as a windows.

Comment: I have the same issue. And all the solutions over here: http://superuser.com/q/804227/109803   don't help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet Connection Sharing with Wireless Hosted Network (WHN) is not providing a DNS server for WHN clients](https://superuser.com/questions/867394/internet-connection-sharing-with-wireless-hosted-network-whn-is-not-providing)

Comment: **This Q is not a dup.** This question is asking why an IP address isn't getting assigned.  The proposed dup deals with a DNS server not being propagated.

Answer (score 0):

There are some more steps that I find are always needed.

Mainly,

- Start the hostednetwork as you have
- go to the Properties of the Internet Connection which you want to share with others (e.g. sharing your wifi connection under another name)
- -> Advanced -> Sharing
- Then allow sharing of the connection by choosing the hosted network to share it with, which is called Local Area Connection *4 for example.

More info: 
[Internet Connection Sharing with Wireless Hosted Network (WHN) is not providing a DNS server for WHN clients](https://superuser.com/questions/867394/internet-connection-sharing-with-wireless-hosted-network-whn-is-not-providing/1051122)