# Windows WiFi hotspot - clients can't connect

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, hotspot, netsh

I configured a WiFi hotspot on Windows, using the command line:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ProvaMi  key=pippo123
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
netsh interface ip set address "TestWIFI" static 192.168.159.1 255.255.255.0 196.168.159.1
```

(basically, the method I described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/940050/41410)

Now, everything works fine, but "sometimes" (where sometimes ranges from some minutes to hours) the network stops working. With "stops working" I mean that the WiFi network is in there, but clients **can't connect**: I tried from the PC, and I get an error message "*I can't connect to this network*"; and from my smartphone, which doesn't even try to connect.

I've seen many comments around the web for a problem of the smartphone which is not getting the IP address... bu I can't either reach that part ("*Obtaining an IP address..*"): the phone simply does not connect.

What I've already tried:

- disabling Windows Firewall
- disabling Power Management for the WiFi interface
- upgrading the WiFi driver

I'm out of ideas on this item, and I can't seem to find a suitable solut

Comment: It is not command configuration problem, besides you said it works for a while. Try to disable network card power saving mode.

Comment: Already tried: see above. By the way: I'm configuring this way: WiFI -> Properties -> Configuration -> Power management -> "Allow the PC to shut down this device to save energy". Right?

Comment: Yes, should leave those setting UNCHECKED, by the way, I recommend you to use a USB wifi adapter to test if you have one. Usually the USB one doens't have power saving setting. If it works, you have work hard to dig in your Internal Wifi card problem.

Comment: Yes: those settings are unchecked. I don't have any WiFi USB adapter at the moment... is there any other "configuration" I need to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of digging into the details of the WiFi controller (that was a **Realtek RTL8723BS**), I found out a setting that allows the correct working of the WiFi hotspot:

- Under WiFi properties -> "Configure..."
- *Advanced* tab
- "WiFi configure" setting. This was set to "Performance"; configuring it to **"WiFi"** makes the WiFi hotspot connection work correctly

This is related to the driver version 3008.8.401.2015, dated 2015.05.13.

I hope this can help someone with the same problem.

Comment: I should add - this hidden Windows "feature" is hidden for a reason - many network drivers were not designed with AP operation in mind, and have bugs and inconsistencies when operating in this mode. It is not unusual for issues like this to arise. Conversely, Intel drivers tend to be fairly good in hotspot mode, in part because Intel have specifically designed hotspot and repeater mode in from the start.

Answer (score -2):

disable **IPv6** from network properties of all WiFi-related connections of windows hotspot

@Arjan I am user like you, what more info I should to provide? Dissasemble of windows drivers and pull request to microsoft?
I had same reproducable problem as main post on clean windows and different wi-fi adapters. Disabling ipv6 completely fixes the problem. I dont know how.
Thanks for downvoting.

Comment: Wow, I guess that worked for you, but it would be quite bad if that's a requirement. Did you disable this on the hotspot, or on the client(s)? Any more details for future readers? Thanks!